# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/os/BuildCompat;

Tags: android, gradle, noclassdeffounderror

i am having a problem dealing with this error, when i run my app it stops and shows error in logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v4.os.BuildCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek-2/lib/arm64,
>   /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]

full error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:
>   Process: homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek, PID: 1919 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/support/v4/os/BuildCompat; 11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/?
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:188)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323) 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/?
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 11-29 13:00:24.538
>   1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v4.os.BuildCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek-1/lib/arm64,
>   /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]] 11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/?
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469) 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:188) 
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173) 
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511) 
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71) 
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323)  11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)  11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  11-29 13:00:24.538
>   1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)  11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  11-29 13:00:24.538
>   1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)  11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:    Suppressed:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.os.BuildCompat
>   11-29 13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 11-29 13:00:24.538
>   1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781) 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841) 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504) 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:            ... 18 more 11-29
>   13:00:24.538 1919-1919/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class
>   loader; no stack trace available

here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/PhotoUtil.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'){
        force = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

i really have no idea how to fix this please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v4-os-bui

Comment: try once clean and rebuild project

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem?  I am facing a similar issue...

Comment: its better if you ask question by yourself. I had a back up with my code and then i clean and rebuild the project and it became alright.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this proplem .And I think problem is :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

You complile with may packages .In some cases, doing so made it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536 limit . So this make NoClassDefFoundError .
Follow this my post: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102081/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v4-util-a)