# Android - redefining class removed from support library (AsyncTaskCompat)

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

Firstly, apologies if I have not included all the required info for this question to be answered. I am somewhat new to Android development and am still getting my head around the build tools, API levels etc. So please let me know if there is any additional info I should provide to help you help me!

After updating my Android project compile sdk version to 27, I realised that version `27.0.2` of `com.android.support:support-v4` no longer includes `AsyncTaskCompat` (that class has been deprecated & removed).

I have a third party library that is not open source, not easily replaceable, is no longer supported and still uses `AsyncTaskCompat`.

Since `AsyncTaskCompat` is open source, I was thinking I could simply reintroduce it somehow by redefining it in my project.

I've tried redefining it under my project in `com.android.support.v4.os` but even though the project compiles without any issues, when I run the section of the app that uses the third party library I get a crash with a class not found error for `AsyncTaskCompat`.

Is there something obvious I might be missing?

Comment: from docs **`AsyncTaskCompat` This class was deprecated in API level 26.0.0.
Use `AsyncTask` directly.**

Comment: The class is deprecated and if removed then it won't work in that library. So you have two choices either to replace that piece of code in the library or develop a work around or replace that library :)

Comment: Thanks Nilu. I have read the docs, that's why I am asking the question. @Umair are you suggesting decompiling the library, changing any of the source files and recompiling it? Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @Rog Yes if you can then change the AsyncTaskCompat to AsyncTask in the library. IMO you have limited choice here. or limit your sdk version to 26 but I believe that's not a good one.

Comment: @Rog If you need to use this library and not replacing it, the simplest solution is to lower your `buildTools` version in your `build.gradle` use a variation of  v25+ of `support-v4` in your `build.gradle` dependency.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No need to add a specific Android Library module.

Only add the classes bellow to your project using the package name "android.support.v4.os":

- [AsyncTaskCompat](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/sources/android-25/android/support/v4/os/AsyncTaskCompat.java)
- [AsyncTaskCompatHoneycomb](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/sources/android-25/android/support/v4/os/AsyncTaskCompatHoneycomb.java)

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question here after another day of hacking away.

It is in fact possible to re-implement these deprecated/removed classes in a way that the dependency will be able to use it.

The steps are described here in case anyone needs it in the future

1. Create a new Android Library module for your app
2. Reimplement the missing classes using the appropriate namespace

In my case I needed to reimplement `android.support.v4.os.AsyncTaskCompat` which is open sourced so all I had to do was copy the code from source.

3. Add the module as a dependency of your main app module.