# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.animation.AnimatorCompatHelper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file

Tags: java, android

I am getting the below error when trying to delete the element in a recycler view in android.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
          "android.support.v4.animation.AnimatorCompatHelper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
```

Although the element is getting deleted but the app crashes out.Let me know if I need to change something in apps gradle file or build gradle file. Please help me out.

> Full Exception Trace:  06-11 12:42:07.867 29844-29844/com.application.aayush.geeta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.application.aayush.geeta, PID: 29844
>                                                                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper;
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator.resetAnimation(DefaultItemAnimator.java:515)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator.animateRemove(DefaultItemAnimator.java:189)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.SimpleItemAnimator.animateDisappearance(SimpleItemAnimator.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.animateDisappearance(RecyclerView.java:3537)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$4.processDisappeared(RecyclerView.java:456)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ViewInfoStore.process(ViewInfoStore.java:246)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep3(RecyclerView.java:3385)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3135)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3568)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
>                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
>                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:846)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1172)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2354)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2081)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1258)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6348)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
>   06-11 12:42:07.870 29844-29844/com.application.aayush.geeta E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
>                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.animation.AnimatorCompatHelper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.application.aayush.geeta-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.application.aayush.geeta-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>                                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

Also when I am trying to debug I am getting the below Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.
Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script 
to proceed with errors:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
       abortOnError false
   }
}
...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v4-os-bui

Comment: Post the full exception stack trace. Post output of `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration debugCompileClasspath` in console where `app` is the name of your app module. Post your build.gradle files.

Comment: Clean Your Project and Check If your are using all the latest App-compact and Recycler Library gradle.

Answer (score 0):

use this library, it solved my problem

compile 'com.github.h6ah4i:android-advancedrecyclerview:develop-SNAPSHOT'

Answer (score -2):

The best solve way is copy missed class to your project.like this:

[image: code tree]