# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/widget/Magnifier;

Tags: android

I was trying to do a Magnifier for TextView using [this document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/magnifier#api_usage)

I have updated the AppCompat Library to 28.+ and the SDK to Android 8 in my Android Studio. Since I could not able to run my app. I appreciate if you can help a bit with this issues. I was exploring and tried all solution like Rebuild/clean project and updated latest support library

**Error Log:**

> Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/widget/Magnifier;
>               at com.oreafeatures.oreafeatures.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:21)

**My Dependencies:**

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 28

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28+'
```

**My Java Code:**

```
        findViewById(R.id.textView).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Magnifier magnifier = new Magnifier(v);
                switch (event.getActionMasked())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        final int[] viewPosition = new int[2];
                        v.getLocationOnScreen(viewPosition);
                       magnifier.show(event.getRawX() - viewPosition[0],
                                event.getRawY() - viewPosition[1]);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        magnifier.dismiss();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Check out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v4-os-bui

Comment: I checked this solution